# Use of uninitialized value $angle in concatenation (.) or string at perl-remd-grp.perl line 22

Tags: perl

I am getting this kind of error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $angle in concatenation (.) or string at perl-remd-grp.perl line 22.
```

It prints all file except 121 and 122.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Preparing input files\n";

$incr=1;

&prepare_input();

sub prepare_input() {
    $dihed=120;
    while ($dihed <= 130) {
        print "Processing dihedral: $dihed\n";
        &write_mdin0();
        $dihed += $incr;
        $angle = $dihed-1;
    }
}

sub write_mdin0 {
    open MDINFILE,'>', "remd-$dihed-grp.ref";
    print MDINFILE <<EOF;
# Replica REPNUM
-O -i remd-${dihed}.rep.REPNUM -p conf-non-pol-1kf1-k-0mm.prmtop -c remd-${angle}-rst.rep.REPNUM -o remd-${dihed}-out.rep.REPNUM -r remd-${dihed}-rst.rep.REPNUM -x remd-${dihed}-nc.rep.REPNUM
EOF
    close MDINFILE;
}
```

It should print all files.

Comment: Is this literally the whole program?  It calls `write_mdin0()` before `$angle` is ever touched and in that function it attempts to interpolate that `$angle` (in here-doc, in `<<EOF`).  Which has not been defined yet ("_initialized_") and thus the warning.

Comment: Can you edit my code? I will be highly grateful. I am a beginner in Perl.

Comment: Fixed indentation.  Notes: (1) **Always** start with`use strict;` (then you'll have to declare variables), and `use warnings;` (and not `-w`) (2) No need for `&` in front of function calls and can be misleading (3) Everything that a function may need should be passed to it as an argument; refrain from using variables from the higher scope (that are indeed visible in the function)  (4) Every `open` **must** be checked for failure, `open ...  or die "Can't ... $!";` (here `$!` has the actual error)

Comment: Can please you edit in my code? I have not understood yet.

Comment: "_Can please you edit in my code_"  -- I don't understand: I did, I fixed indentation so that the code is clearer to read.   If you mean that I fix the programming error in it then that I shouldn't do -- that's what the answers are for.  But I can't answer because I don't know what that `$angle` should be initialized to.  I did tell you what seems to be the problem: `$angle` is used (in the function) before it has any value.  Give it some starting value, like you did with `$dihed`?

Comment: $angle and $dihed use for print the value. There is no such particular function.

Comment: In your `prepare_input()` function you call `write_mdin0()` function, and in it `$angle` is used (...`remd-${angle}`...).  But `$angle` is not defined before `write_mdin0()` is called the first time. So when it's used it is undefined and you get a warning for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `use strict` to your code and then consider the scope of your variables.

In `write_mdin0()` you use a global variable called `$angle`. But look at your `while` loop.

```
while ($dihed <= 130) {
    print "Processing dihedral: $dihed\n";
    &write_mdin0();    # <--- $angle is used in here
    $dihed += $incr;
    $angle = $dihed-1; # <--- But $angle isn't set until here
}
```

The first time through this loop, `$angle` hasn't been given a value when `write_mdin0()` is called.

I don't really understand your code, but perhaps you need to initialise `$angle` at the same time as you initialise `$dihed`.

```
sub prepare_input() {
    $dihed = 120;
    $angle = $dihed - 1;
    while ($dihed <= 130) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Relying on global variables is to ignore one of the most useful lessons in the history of software development. Unless you have a very good reason, a subroutine should only use variables that are defined within it or parameters that are passed to it.

I'll also add, that using `&` on subroutine calls is a hangover from Perl 4. It is very rarely needed in Perl 5 and using it only makes your code harder to understand.

Update: I imagine your code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Preparing input files\n";

prepare_input();

sub prepare_input {
    my $dihed = 120;
    my $angle = $dihed - 1;

    # Only used in this subroutine, so define it here
    my $incr = 1;

    while ($dihed <= 130) {
        print "Processing dihedral: $dihed\n";
        write_mdin0($dihed, $angle);
        $dihed += $incr;
        $angle = $dihed-1;
    }
}

sub write_mdin0 {
    my ($dihed, $angle) = @_;

    open my $mdin_fh,'>', "remd-$dihed-grp.ref";
    print $mdin_fh <<EOF;
# Replica REPNUM
-O -i remd-${dihed}.rep.REPNUM -p conf-non-pol-1kf1-k-0mm.prmtop -c remd-${angle}-rst.rep.REPNUM -o remd-${dihed}-out.rep.REPNUM -r remd-${dihed}-rst.rep.REPNUM -x remd-${dihed}-nc.rep.REPNUM
EOF
    # Lexical filehandle closed automatically
    # as the variable goes out of scope
}
```